# Split Filenames with the help of names in another file and save the text file in Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, operating-system, file-handling

I am on Windows.
This might be a simple question but I don't know how to use the OS module to conduct the following

I have a folder named 'modules' with a few text files. File location:

```
F = C:\\X\\Data\modules
```

And within this folder I have about 3000 text files with good and bad reviews about a product in the form of `.txt` files.

I also have two `.txt` files `good.txt` and `bad.txt` which have a list of the names of the good and bad reviews.
Location of the files are

```
good.txt = C:\\X\\Data\good.txt
bad.txt = C:\\X\\Data\bad.txt
```

For example the file `good.txt` looks as follows and contains the names of the good files in the folder `modules`.

```
['cv148_18084.txt', 'cv652_15653.txt', 'cv444_9975.txt', 'c282_6833.txt', 'cv602_8830.txt', 
 'cv941_10718.txt',  'cv223_28923.txt', 'cv198_19313.txt', 'cv481_7930.txt','cv723_9002.txt',...]
```

The file `bad.txt` also looks the same way with the names of bad reviews about the product.

My doubt being, how do I use these file names and then look through the folder `module` and when I find the file segregate it into two other folders called `good` and `bad`.

Locations being:

```
Good folder = C:\\X\\Data\good
Bad folder = C:\\X\\Data\bad
```

How do I use python to complete this task.

I am new to stack and I don't know if I have asked the question in the right format, forgive me for I am still learning.

Thank you for your time, support and effort.

**EDIT**

I know I must use

```
>>> os.path.exists(r'C:\\x\\Data\modules\'nameoffile'.txt)
```

But I do now know how to go through the entire file, good.txt and iterate this process.
I also do now know how to save the file in case I find it into the other foder

Comment: read the file ``C:\\X\\Data\good`` iterate over the lines, check if file exists using ```os.path.exists``` then move to ``good`` folder & repeat the same for ``bad``.

Comment: Respected Sir, Where can I look up the documentation for os.

Comment: [`os.path.exists`](https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter16_os.html#os-path-exists)